# CalendarView in Android works nicely in emulator, but on device is completely different

Tags: java, android, calendar, emulation

Edit: It's been fixed! The solution was to update my device so that the API matched the emulator. Seems obvious in hindsight but I had figured that the lower API development target would have avoided this problem. Thanks for the tips!

I'm developing a simple app that uses a calendar to switch which part of a guide you want to look at. In the emulator, I get this nice calendar on top, with text on the bottom.

However, when I run the app on my device, the calendar explodes into all possible months, with no text anywhere!

Is there any way I can force the app to use the more compact version of the calendar?

(I don't have enough rep to post images, so here's an imgur album demonstrating my problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRdcl.jpg)

Emulator is API23 and Device is API22. The project is being developed for API14 though, could this really be the problem?

Here is the .xml for the CalendarView

```
<CalendarView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minDate="04/06/2009"
        android:maxDate="01/31/2010"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        />
```

And in the .java file I have a listener which changes the text.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

/*
irrelevant code
*/
        calendar = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);       
/*
more irrelevant code
*/
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int i, int     i1, int i2) { // year, month, day

        int j = 1;
        boolean found = false;
        while((j < allDays.length-1) && !found)
        {
            if((allDays[j].getMonth() == i1+1) && (allDays[j].getDay() == i2))
            {
                found = true;
            }
        else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
        if(found)
        {
            index = j;
            changeText.setText(allDays[j].getGuide());
            adjustSize();
        }
        else
        {
            changeText.setText("No action today");
        }
    }
```

Hopefully that is enough information.

Comment: Post your code how you are using it ?

Comment: what is android version of emulator and device ? please specific your question with version